# String to int in imageJ

Tags: java, imagej

Below is a section of my code:

```
String xdim = fake.substring(0,index);
IJ.showMessage("xdim "+xdim);
String ydim = fake.substring((index+1));
int xwidth = Integer.parseInt(xdim);
```

it compiles okay, and the MessageDialog Box produces the statement "xdim 400.0".
The program then produces an error at the line

```
int xwidth = Integer.parseInt(xdim);
```

I saw answered questions on this website saying this was the method to use. It appears that my string is not being parsed as an Int.

Any ideas?

I tried converting the String to a double and from a double to an int but got a compiling error stating "double cannot be dereferenced"

Thanks for your time

Bateman

Comment: what is the value of `xdim`

Comment: Are you getting a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

Comment: `400.0` is not an int, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
int xwidth = Integer.parseInt(xdim);
```

you should try

```
double xwidth = Double.parseDouble(xdim);
```

or

```
float xwidth = Float.parseFloat(xdim);
```

As you clearly have a decimal fraction there (`.0`), giving a NumberFormatException when trying to be parsed as int...

If you want to use xwidth as an int, you should use [Math.round](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) too.

Beware, if you pass `double` as an argument, you'll get a `long` back, but if you pass a `float`, the return will be of `int`...

```
int xwidth = Math.round(Float.parsefloat(xdim));
```